# How to add marker(s) to Google Map using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add marker(s) to Google Map through jQuery method at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/J9Rwx/1/) and this is the code which I am using:

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.889318);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: title
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    });
});
```

As you can see I am using this snippet to generate markers on the map

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: event.latLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                title: title
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        });
```

but it is not adding any Marker(s) to the map! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define the variable "title".  (Firebug is your friend.)

```
var cnt = 0;
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            title: "test title #" + ++cnt
        });
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/rMc3u/3/)

Comment: Thanks McGarnagle, Can you please also let me know how I can add a sequence of numbers for title instead of having a static string? once again thanks

Comment: @MonaCoder sure, just define a variable and increment each time you create a marker.  See my edit above.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment and help. I am going to work on registering each markers lat and long values and displaying them on a table

Comment: I am not sure how hard it is gonna be but I will my best :-)